# FTPでの550エラー解消について

Tags: ftp

お世話になっています。
初めてのVPS設定であちこち躓いているのですが、FTPで出る550エラーの解消について質問させてください。

【準備】
CentOS7で構築しています。

『ftpusr』と言うユーザーを作成。

```sh
usermod -G apache ftpusr
```

vsftpdを導入

```sh
yum install vsftpd
vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

anonymous_enable=NO
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
ls_recurse_enable=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
tcp_wrappers=YES
pasv_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/user_conf
```

ポートの解放済み

/etc/vsftpd/user_conf/ftpusr　作成済、中には「local_root=/var/www/html」を記載しています。
/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list にもftpusr追加済み

---

この状態でFTPを試して、ログインは出来ました。rootへの移動許可も試すつもりで設定したので、rootへの移動も出来ています。
ですが、何かしら操作をすると、

```sh
550 Create directory operation failed.
553 Could not create file.
```

と表示され、アップロードやファイル作成などが出来ません。

/var/www/htmlフォルダ以下は

```sh
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chown apache:apache {} +
find /var/www/html -type f -exec chown apache:apache {} +
```

で設定してあります。

SELinuxについてはDisableになっています。

初心者ですのでおかしな設定等あるかもしれませんが、ご教授頂ければと思います。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `ftpusr` は `apache` グループに属しているので、`find ... -type d -exec chmod 775 ...`, `find ... -type f -exec chmod 664 ...` とするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ユーザーを新規で作る、と言う事自体が初めてで、グループの意味辺り把握しきれていませんでした。アドバイスになるほど、と。ありがとうございました。大変助かりました。